# Restoring Oracle XE database

Tags: oracle, oracle-10g, windows

I had Oracle 10G XE installed on my Windows machine. The machine got corrupted and I will have to install Oracle again. I did not take a backup in the form of SQL queries.

How can I use the old database with the new installation?

Comment: How can you restore a backup from nothing? The answer is: you can't.

Comment: Your question is unclear: what were you able to recover from the "corrupted" machine? Do you still have all the database files? Are you sure they're not corrupt themselves?

Comment: I never said data corrupted. Its just windows needed to reinstall. In Mysql could move db folders from old installations to new. How can I do it in Oracle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a backup of the:

- existing datafiles (SYSTEM01.DBF, SYSAUX01.DBF, UNDOTBS01.DBF, USERS01.DBF or similar) and tempfile (TEMP01.DBF - actually its not really needed, but keep it simple...)
- controlfiles (CONTROL01.CTL, CONTROL02.CTL, or similar)
- redo logs (REDO01.LOG, REDO02.LOG, etc..)
- and the database parameterfile (ORACLE_HOME/database/initXE.ora or    spfileXE.ora)

Note the path of these files, as you should copy them back to their original path if you want to make it simple for yourself.
You can simply move/rename the whole existing Oracle directory if you want.

Install the new operating system, install Oracle 10g XE again at the same directory (so delete the previous installation after making backup of the above), let it create a new database and listener. When its done, stop the database and the belonging service at Windows Services by stopping the OracleServiceXE service. Now copy back the above files at their original place, and start the database by starting the OracleServiceXE service. The database should start and open after performing a crash recovery if your computer was shut down uncleanly earlier.

Note that, this is and oversimplified example of a way more complex process, and it assumes that you put everything to the place where they originally were.